# pygraphviz installation failed when building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension

Tags: python, pip, networkx, graphviz, pygraphviz

I'm trying to install pygraphviz on Win7, python 3.5

Using following command:

```
C:\Users\...>C:\Python35\python.exe -m pip install pygraphviz
```

Also tried to add install options, but it didn't help:

```
--install-option="--library-path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz\graphviz-2.38\release\lib\debug\lib" --install-option="--include-path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz\graphviz-2.38\release\include"
```

And here is the return:

```
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\build'
    writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying pygraphviz\graphviz.i -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz\graphviz_wrap.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pygraphviz
    running build_ext
    building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\
\Users\\ebarhab\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-iot7onp2\\pygraphviz\\setup.py'
;f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n')
;f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ebar
hab\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-hrnu16e0-record\install-record.txt --single-version-e
xternally-managed --compile "--library-path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz\grap
hviz-2.38\release\lib\debug\lib" "--include-path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz
\graphviz-2.38\release\include"" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ebarhab\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\pip-build-iot7onp2\pygraphviz\
```

Could you help me solve this issue?

Thanks,
Bartek

Comment: Do you have Visual C++ 14.0? It's [required to compile extensions for Python 3.5](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Which_Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_compiler_to_use_with_a_specific_Python_version_.3F).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @phd! Installing Visual C++ 14.0 helped indeed, but after that i faced another issue:
 `graphviz_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PyIOBase_Type`
Can you help me here as well?

Comment: I used google and in [issue 74](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/74) found [this patch](https://github.com/Kagami/pygraphviz/commit/fe442dc16accb629c3feaf157af75f67ccabbd6e.diff). Try it. Seems like an old bug, still not completely resolved. See aslo [issue 116](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/116).